# PDF of large size is not displaying , while the small one(PDFs having one page) is getting displayed. I am using PostgreSql database here

Tags: php, html, sql, postgresql, base64

```
<?php
$cn= pg_connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sampledb user=postgres 
password=xxxx');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query=pg_query($cn,"select * from books where id=$id");
while($row=pg_fetch_array($query))
{
 $id = $row['id']; 
 $book_pdf=$row['book_pdf'];
 $pdf=pg_unescape_bytea($row['book_pdf']);     
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
 <body>
  <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo $pdf; ?>" 
    type="application/pdf" style="height:1000px;width:100%">
  </object>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I encode my PDFs in base64 format and then save it in PosgreSql bytea column and then I give pg_unescape_bytea() to extract base64 data. Can someone tell how to handle large amount of base64 data.

Comment: What is your max execution time?

Comment: Why are you send a PDF in an object tag? Just send the contents raw, all modern browsers know how to deal with it

Comment: any links? how to send the contents raw